# bivariate LISA in R

Tags: r, spdep, ggplot

I am new to R. I am interested to estimate Moran's I result. Specifically, a map of the bivariate spatial correlation (bivariate LISA) in R using spdep and ggplot2 package. I have points data over different locations, in CSV format. I have two variables- A and B. And, I want to examine the relationship -- how A & B are associated with each other by means of high A and high B, Low A and High B like that.

I am following this Q&A (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664728/create-a-map-of-spatial-clusters-lisa-in-r). When I am running--- patterns <- as.character(interaction(xp > 0, W%*%yp > 0)), then it is showing this error--- Error in xp %*% W : non-conformable arguments. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Well, we would need to see your code and an example of your data to have any idea on what "you are doing wrong". I would however, recommend taking a look at the `rgeoda` library for this analysis. The code interface is much simpler than `spdep` and the results are digested in a way that are quite a bit easier to use.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your attention to my problem. You can see the data and code here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71783714/mapping-lisa-cluster-in-r?noredirect=1#comment126894184_71783714

Comment: Cross-posting is highly frowned upon. Where did you get the code for the LISA (local Moran's)? This looks a lot like code I wrote, sometime ago, implementing Chen's (2015) approximation of a the cross correlation (is now the `crossCorrelation` function in the spatialEco library). The Wij matrix should be an inverse power or negative exponent of a distance matrix. You are deriving a binary contingency matrix, which is not correct.

Comment: Thank you. I got code from https://gist.github.com/rafapereirabr/5348193abf779625f5e8c5090776a228 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177590/map-of-bivariate-spatial-correlation-in-r-bivariate-lisa/45266460#45266460 . That means I am using the wrong code :( I am will kook for spatialEco==crossCorrelation.

Answer (score 1):

The `rgeoda` library simplifies implementation of the univariate and bivariate (lapse rate) LISA considerably.

**Add libraries and example data**

```
library(sf)
library(rgeoda)

guerry <- st_read(system.file("extdata", "Guerry.shp", 
                  package = "rgeoda"))
```

**Calculate spatial weights matrix (Wij)**

```
wij <- queen_weights(guerry)
```

**Specify a univariate Local Moran and plot results**

```
lisa <- local_moran(wij, guerry['Crm_prs'])
  ( lms <- lisa_values(gda_lisa = lisa) )
  ( pvals <- lisa_pvalues(lisa) )
  
# False discovery rate
( fdr <- lisa_fdr(lisa, 0.05) )

lisa_colors <- lisa_colors(lisa)
lisa_labels <- lisa_labels(lisa)
lisa_clusters <- lisa_clusters(lisa)

plot(st_geometry(guerry), col=sapply(lisa_clusters, 
     function(x){return(lisa_colors[[x+1]])}), 
     border = "#333333", lwd=0.2)
title(main = "Univaraite Local Moran")
legend('bottomleft', legend = lisa_labels, fill = lisa_colors, 
       border = "#eeeeee")
```

[image: univariate lisa]

**Specify a bivariate Local Moran and plot results**

```
( qsa <- local_bimoran(wij, guerry[c('Crm_prs', 'Litercy')]) )
  lisa_colors <- lisa_colors(qsa)
  lisa_labels <- lisa_labels(qsa)
  lisa_clusters <- lisa_clusters(qsa)

plot(st_geometry(guerry), col=sapply(lisa_clusters, 
     function(x){return(lisa_colors[[x+1]])}), 
     border = "#333333", lwd=0.2)
title(main = "Bivaraite Local Moran")
legend('bottomleft', legend = lisa_labels, fill = lisa_colors, 
       border = "#eeeeee")
```

[image: bivariate lisa]

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried but it is showing the whole area as Isolated :(

Comment: Make sure that you are not using multipart `MULTIPOLYGON` geometry. Just print your sf object and it will indicate the geometry in the geometry column.  You can explode it to singlepart using `x <- st_cast(x, "POLYGON")`.